# Is there a way to run a set number of processes in the background in Ubuntu with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am trying to run processes in parallel by sending them to the background using "&" after the command, but this causes over 20,000 processes to run in the background, which overloads the computer. Is there a way to limit the number of processes running at once to a set number, like 100?

What I am currently doing involves calling the following python function which runs a bash script with the subprocess module:

```
def xtract(self):
        print(f'**** Extracting frame: {self.frame}')
        sub.run(f'./multimer.sh {outdir} {self.count} {self.frame} {"+".join(self.segs)} {pdb} {dcd} &', shell=True)
```

in the following loop:

```
for m in multimers:
        m.xtract()
```

However, there are typically over 20,000 objects in the list "multimers" which causes too many processes to run in the background, overloading the system. Is there a simple fix to this such that no more than a set number of (say 100) processes run at once while still iterating over the entire list? The solution can be in python or bash, it doesn't really matter as long as the number of processes is limited to a set number.

Comment: maybe asynchronous programming?

Comment: in pure `bash` we'd keep track of the number of backgrounded processes, halt the generation of background processes at a given limit until `wait [-n]` shows a backgrounded process has completed, at which point it's safe to spawn a new background process; sooo ... in python ... is there a way to know when any background processes have completed so that you can procees with spawning a new background process? (or is that what you're asking?); a google search on `python limit number of background processes` brings up quite a few hits; replace `python` with `bash` for another set of google hits

Comment: See **Process Pools** here https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html